# How to make implicit conversion work in Scala?

Tags: scala

Can't understand why my code doesn't work. I have a simple trait with implicit conversion:

```
trait Bool {

  impl =>

  implicit def bool2Ops(b: Boolean): BoolOps = BoolOps(b)

  case class BoolOps(a: Boolean) {
    def or (b: Boolean) = impl.or (a,b)
    def and(b: Boolean) = impl.and(a,b)
  }

  def and(a: Boolean, b: Boolean): Boolean
  def or (a: Boolean, b: Boolean): Boolean

}
```

In the same package I have an implementation:

```
class PlainBool extends Bool {

  def and(a: Boolean, b: Boolean): Boolean = a && b
  def or (a: Boolean, b: Boolean): Boolean = a || b

}

object PlainBool extends App {

  // ok
  val res = new PlainBool().and(true, false)
  println {res}

  // failed
  println { true.and(false) }

}
```

But my conversion does not work. Any ideas why?

**UPD**

As @Rüdiger Klaehn mentioned my `PlainBool` companion object doesn't extend my `Bool` trait. Therefore, it doesn't see the implicit conversion function. So what I need is to make `PlainBool` object extend the trait and this should fix the scope:

```
object PlainBool extends Bool with App {

  println { true and false }

  def and(a: Boolean, b: Boolean): Boolean = a && b
  def or (a: Boolean, b: Boolean): Boolean = a || b

}
```

And in that case `PlainBool` class is redundant.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. Just add named aliases for && and ||?

Comment: It is just a scala playground example. I want to try a scala syntax here. I saw a similar example of trait `Boot`, but there was not any impl for it, so I do not know how to implement it right.

Comment: Did you try to place this implicit conversion into Bool _companion object_? So you can import it into your scope. In your implementation it seems that the implicit conversion is not in scope.

Comment: Why? I extended Bool trait (see PlainBool). So it should be there. By the way, all these classes (class, trait, and object) in the same package.

Comment: The App object is a *companion object* to PlainBool, but does not *extend* PlainBool.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I see my mistake now.